# Image retraining in tensorflow, changing the simple softmax layer to multilayer CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Tensorflow has released a tutorial for transfer learning named Image retraining that can be found in here: 
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining

What they are doing is using a pre-trained model on inception v3 and then they change only the very last layer (softmax regression layer) and train it on the new dataset. This is very understandable and in fact a common practice in transfer learning.

I have tried their method on my dataset (which is a small dataset) and I have applied all the suggestion to get a better result from the data augmentation to change the number of steps but I did not modify their code by any means. The accuracy I got is relatively bad ~70%.

I am thinking of the possibility of training a small neural network on top of the given model, namely, changing the last layer from a simple regression to a more sophisticated network.

Here is the part of their code where they modify the softmax layer:

```
def add_final_training_ops(class_count, final_tensor_name, bottleneck_tensor):
  """Adds a new softmax and fully-connected layer for training.
  We need to retrain the top layer to identify our new classes, so this function
  adds the right operations to the graph, along with some variables to hold the
  weights, and then sets up all the gradients for the backward pass.
  The set up for the softmax and fully-connected layers is based on:
  https://tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html
  Args:
    class_count: Integer of how many categories of things we're trying to
    recognize.
    final_tensor_name: Name string for the new final node that produces results.
    bottleneck_tensor: The output of the main CNN graph.
  Returns:
    The tensors for the training and cross entropy results, and tensors for the
    bottleneck input and ground truth input.
  """
  with tf.name_scope('input'):
    bottleneck_input = tf.placeholder_with_default(
        bottleneck_tensor, shape=[None, BOTTLENECK_TENSOR_SIZE],
        name='BottleneckInputPlaceholder')

    ground_truth_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                                        [None, class_count],
                                        name='GroundTruthInput')

  # Organizing the following ops as `final_training_ops` so they're easier
  # to see in TensorBoard
  layer_name = 'final_training_ops'
  with tf.name_scope(layer_name):
    with tf.name_scope('weights'):
      layer_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([BOTTLENECK_TENSOR_SIZE, class_count], stddev=0.001), name='final_weights')
      variable_summaries(layer_weights)
    with tf.name_scope('biases'):
      layer_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([class_count]), name='final_biases')
      variable_summaries(layer_biases)
    with tf.name_scope('Wx_plus_b'):
      logits = tf.matmul(bottleneck_input, layer_weights) + layer_biases
      tf.summary.histogram('pre_activations', logits)

  final_tensor = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name=final_tensor_name)
  tf.summary.histogram('activations', final_tensor)

  with tf.name_scope('cross_entropy'):
    cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
        labels=ground_truth_input, logits=logits)
    with tf.name_scope('total'):
      cross_entropy_mean = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
  tf.summary.scalar('cross_entropy', cross_entropy_mean)

  with tf.name_scope('train'):
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(FLAGS.learning_rate).minimize(
        cross_entropy_mean)

  return (train_step, cross_entropy_mean, bottleneck_input, ground_truth_input,
          final_tensor)


def add_evaluation_step(result_tensor, ground_truth_tensor):
  """Inserts the operations we need to evaluate the accuracy of our results.

  Args:
    result_tensor: The new final node that produces results.
    ground_truth_tensor: The node we feed ground truth data
    into.

  Returns:
    Tuple of (evaluation step, prediction).
  """
  with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
    with tf.name_scope('correct_prediction'):
      prediction = tf.argmax(result_tensor, 1)
      correct_prediction = tf.equal(
          prediction, tf.argmax(ground_truth_tensor, 1))
    with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
      evaluation_step = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
  tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', evaluation_step)
  return evaluation_step, prediction
```

However, I am facing two main problems. First, I am not if this a good idea or not? would I be just wasting in my effort in doing something useless? Second, they are using the simple MNIST tutorial as a model for the last layer, say that I would use their Expert MNIST tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros) I am lost on what to do or how to configure it?.

Any suggestions on what can I do?

Comment: How small is your new dataset? How many classes do you have? Are they "imbalanced" (i.e. how many cases are there per class, and is there a similar number of cases for each class)? I ran the `retrain.py` script on three VERY poorly labeled classes, each containing 100 examples and got about 70% accuracy. And that's fine for me -- I expect that I can get significantly better results by throwing away mislabeled images, and by increasing the number of cases. I let you know what's my result after applying those changes...

Comment: OK, I get about 93% after removing 60 wrongly labeled images from the third class (so I have the following numbers of cases: 100, 100, 40).

Comment: @ponadto The dataset has about 40 classes and they are highly imbalanced e.g. one class has around 800 images then the next 3 classes have about 200 images and the remaining classes have <20 images. The thing is when you have such an imbalance in your dataset, choosing accuracy as your metric is not recommended because the accuracy in this case usually is the dominant class accuracy. Can you try printing the confusion matrix or a weighted accuracy and check your the results again?